# No visible @interface declares the selector 'ordinalityOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:' in IOS

Tags: ios, nsdate

I try to  calculate number of days between two NSDate I used this https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/Articles/dtCalendricalCalculations.html

```
Listing 13 Days between two dates, as the number of midnights between

@implementation NSCalendar (MySpecialCalculations)

-(NSInteger)daysWithinEraFromDate:(NSDate *) startDate toDate:(NSDate *) endDate
{
     NSInteger startDay=[self ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
          inUnit: NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:startDate];
     NSInteger endDay=[self ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
          inUnit: NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:endDate];
     return endDay-startDay;
}
@end
```

This is my code:

```
@implementation MapViewController
-(NSInteger)daysWithinEraFromDate:(NSDate *) startDate toDate:(NSDate *) endDate
{
    NSInteger startDay=[self ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                       inUnit: NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:startDate];
    NSInteger endDay=[self ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                     inUnit: NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:endDate];
    return endDay-startDay;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

@end
```

But I met this error.Please help me!!

```
 No visible @interface for 'MapViewController' declares the selector 'ordinalityOfUnit:inUnit:forDate:'
```

Comment: The error is quite clear. The `MapViewController` does not have such a method. Since you have that method on the `NSCalendar` class, you should call the method on an instance of that class instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use like this:

```
[[NSCalendar currentCalendar] ordinalityOfUnit:NSDayCalendarUnit
                                       inUnit: NSEraCalendarUnit forDate:startDate];
```